# Deleting Text between Two Rows with Dynamic Headers

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I am trying to delete text between two rows that occur multiple times in my Excel spreadsheet. The number of rows in between the text headers varies each time. One of the row headers remains the same, but the first row header will change each time, from Property A to Property B to Property C. I found an answer that helps me fairly well, but how do I use a wildcard symbol to make my starting string be "Property:*"?

```
Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String
Dim DELETEMODE As Boolean
Dim DelRng As Range
    strStart = "Property: A"
    strEnd = "Total"

DELETEMODE = False
For r = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'first to last used row
    
    If Range("A" & r).Value = strEnd Then DELETEMODE = False
    
    If DELETEMODE Then
        'Create a Delete Range that will be used at the end
        If DelRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DelRng = Range("A" & r)
        Else
            Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, Range("A" & r))
        End If
    End If
    
    If Range("A" & r).Value = strStart Then DELETEMODE = True
Next r

'Delete the Range compiled from above
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
```

Comment: Try using `instr`?

Comment: You could also use `.Find()` for partial strings, allowing you to get your first header row, second heard row, then delete everything between said rows.

Comment: Can you explain more about where to insert the .Find()? At strStart? I'm still new to this and finding my way along the code!

Answer (score 0):

Quick example with regard to comments on using `find()`:

```
Sub test()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Dim firstFoundCell As Range:  Set firstFoundCell = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).Find(what:="Property: ", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If firstFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                Exit For
            Else
                Dim secondFoundCell As Range:  Set secondFoundCell = .Range(.Cells(firstFoundCell.Row + 1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).Find(what:="Property: ", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
                If secondFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Dim deleteRange As Range
                    If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set deleteRange = .Range(.Rows(firstFoundCell.Row + 1), .Rows(secondFoundCell.Row - 1))
                    Else
                        Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, .Range(.Rows(firstFoundCell.Row + 1), .Rows(secondFoundCell.Row - 1)))
                    End If
                    i = firstFoundCell.Row + 1
                    Set firstFoundCell = Nothing
                    Set secondFoundCell = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not deleteRange Is Nothing Then deleteRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on filtering followed by processing of visible cell coordinates. Will not work if there is a mismatch between "Property - Total" pairs

```
Sub DelGaps()
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange)
        Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Property*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Total"
        
        On Error GoTo out
        Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ReDim a(0 To Rng.Count - 1)
        For Each cl In Rng
            a(i) = cl.Row: i = i + 1
        Next
        
        For i = UBound(a) To 0 Step -2
            rfrom = a(i - 1) + 1
            rto = a(i) - 1
            If rto > rfrom Then _
                .Rows(rfrom & ":" & rto).Interior.Color = vbRed 'Delete
        Next
    
out:
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Red rows will be deleted
[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Between Headers and Totals

**A Quick Fix**

- When considering using wild cards, the Like operator should immediately come to mind.
- `' ***` indicates the changes.

```vb
Sub QuickFix()

    Dim dT As Double: dT = Timer

    Const strStart As String = "Property: *" ' ***
    Const strEnd As String = "Total" ' ***
    
    Dim DelRng As Range
    Dim r As Long ' ***
    Dim DELETEMODE As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'first to last used row
        
        If Range("A" & r).Value = strEnd Then DELETEMODE = False
        
        If DELETEMODE Then
            'Create a Delete Range that will be used at the end
            If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Range("A" & r)
            Else
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, Range("A" & r))
            End If
        End If
        
        If Range("A" & r).Value Like strStart Then DELETEMODE = True ' ***
    
    Next r
    
    'Delete the Range compiled from above
    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

    Debug.Print Timer - dT

End Sub
```

- There are a few issues with this code.
- Firstly, it is a little bit slow which is covered in the *Improvement* in detail and mainly consists of combining the appropriate ranges (not each cell) into the *Delete range*.
- Secondly, let's focus on what will be deleted if your data accidentally has missing *Totals*. Consider the following extreme-case image:

[image]

- What should be deleted? Here is what happens after using your amended code.

[image]

- Here is what I would like to happen covered in the *Improvement*.

[image]

- In a nutshell, all *Properties* should stay alive and rows should only be deleted above the *Totals* if there previously was a *Property* row detected. In this case, only row 18 was deleted.

**The Improvement**

```vb
Sub DeleteBetweenHeaders()
    
    Dim dT As Double: dT = Timer
    
    Const strStart As String = "Property: *"
    Const strEnd As String = "Total"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim fr As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        r = r + 1
        If cell.Value Like strStart Then
            fr = r + 1 ' write the next row to the first row variable
        ElseIf cell.Value = strEnd Then
            lr = r - 1 ' write the previous row to the last row variable
            If fr > 0 Then ' the first row is set
                If lr >= fr Then ' there is a gap
                    If drg Is Nothing Then
                        Set drg = rg.Cells(fr).Resize(lr - fr + 1)
                    Else
                        Set drg = Union(drg, rg.Cells(fr).Resize(lr - fr + 1))
                    End If
                'Else ' lr < fr i.e. there is no gap; do nothing
                End If
                fr = 0 ' reset the first row
            'Else ' there is no first row yet; do nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then drg.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

    Debug.Print Timer - dT

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will read it through so I can understand the nuances better, I'm very new to all of this!